# linear Dataseries Say 0 on Y Axis Having Issue

Tags: highcharts

Linear Dataseries Say all y axis is 0, Autoscaling on y axis is not working as desired.

High stock version - 1.3.1

DataSeries to be plotted,

[[1149724800000,0],[1149811200000,0],[1150070400000,0],[1150156800000,0],[1150243200000,0],[1150329600000,0],[1150416000000,0],[1150675200000,0],[1150761600000,0],[1150848000000,0],[1150934400000,0],[1151020800000,0],[1151280000000,0],[1151366400000,0],[1151452800000,0],[1151539200000,0],[1151625600000,0]]

OR

[[1149724800000,20],[1149811200000,20],[1150070400000,20],[1150156800000,20],[1150243200000,20],[1150329600000,20],[1150416000000,20],[1150675200000,20],[1150761600000,20],[1150848000000,20],[1150934400000,20],[1151020800000,20],[1151280000000,20],[1151366400000,20],[1151452800000,20],[1151539200000,20],[1151625600000,20]]

Try Above series with Y min set to 0 and Y Min to Auto.

Comment: I assume that problem is with 0 values in center, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 0 values displayed in the center. 
The only way I found to get round it was to either use tickPositions and pass range values across to it for the data based of min/max values and ones in between or to use the tickPositioner call back function to return to go through the data and return the tick values based on these.

Still fairly new to highcharts so there is probably another way I don't know of. If anyone knows how to have 0 values displayed at the bottom of the chart while it auto-scales then please post as I would love to know how/if its possible.

Edit: turns out this isn't really possible currently, only way to get around it is to set min/max values and that won't allow auto scaling but at least it stop there from being any middle 0 values.